# Is compact() and with() interchangeable?

Tags: php, laravel

There seems to be two most used way to pass data to the view and though there are several questions asking the difference between the two functions, I don't see a single stackoverflow answer that explains whether they are interchangeable, which is used more often and if they are not interchangeable, in what situation to use the two functions.

Comment: Both are not related. compact() is php function, and with() is laravel function. They are not interchangeable, read doc http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php

Comment: @ZaheerAttar I understand that one is a php function and the other is a Laravel function but they seem to be used in the same context, same situation for a rookie programmer like me, so I would like to know exactly what situation to use which function.

Comment: `compact` is a PHP function which does things no userland function implementation could possibly imitate. So, `with` cannot possibly do the same thing that `compact` does, so they can't be interchangeable.

Comment: `compact()` is used to create array using separate variables. `with()` is function just to pass the data to view. You can not pass data to view using `compact()`, yes but you can pass an array to view generated using  `compact()` using `with()`.

Comment: You might want to update your question to explain *why* you think they're interchangeable?

Comment: @deceze I can't figure out the difference in terms of when to use the function so it seems interchangeable to me, I'm pretty sure its not but I asked the question wondering what their difference is in terms of when to use either function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[compact()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) is a standard PHP Function that builds an array from a list of variables, assigning the variable name as the array element key, and the variable value as the array element value. It can be used as a convenient way of passing variables to a view in Laravel, because Laravel's `View::make()` will accept a second argument of an array of key/value pairs.
You could just as easily specify an array of key/value pairs, but PHP's `compact()` provides an easy way of doing this.

```
$x = "Hello";
$y = "world";
$view = View::make('myViewName', compact('x', 'y');
```

is the same as

```
$x = "Hello";
$y = "world";
$view = View::make('myViewName', ['x' => $x, 'y' => $y]);
```

but with `compact()` your variables must already exist. Specifying an array manually is more flexible because you could do

```
$x = "Hello";
$y = "world";
$view = View::make('myViewName', ['salutation' => $x, 'addressTo' => $y]);
```

which would give variables called `$salutation` and `$addressTo` inside your blade template, even though your original variables were just called `$x` and `$y`.

or you can even do

```
$view = View::make('myViewName', ['salutation' => "Hello", 'addressTo' => "world"]);
```

`with()` is Laravel-specific, and (in this View building context) allows you to specify individual keys and values to be passed to the view. The main difference is that you can specify the key name as whatever you want (in much the same way as using your own-built array as a second argument to `View::make()`), and the value can be a direct return from a function call.

```
$x = "Hello";
$y = "world";
$view = View::make('myViewName')->with('x', $x)->with('y', $y);
```

or

```
$view = View::make('myViewName')->with('x', "Hello")->with('y', "World");
```

or

```
$view = View::make('myViewName')
    ->with('salutation', "Hello")
    ->with('addressTo', "World");
```

It's basically the same as passing a user-built array to `View::make()`, but arguably more readable

In both cases, the key/value pairs (whether specified via the second argument to `View::make()` or using `with()`) are extracted inside the blade template, with the key being used for the element name.

The two approaches can even be used together.